# Angular 2 can no longer import components into other components with modules

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I redid my architecture recently and created modules for every component so I could lazy load them when routing.  This works great.  However, I'm having issues simply importing components into other components now and not entirely sure why.  I'm importing like this:

```
import {TrackingComponent} from './tracking/tracking.component';
```

and my selector is simply:

```
<tracking></tracking>
```

when I run this I get:

error_handler.js:46 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'tracking' is not a known element:

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  The module/component distinction is a little muddy in mind at the moment.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you update your TrackingComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to import components classes into other classes. That does absolutely nothing (in the context of Angular) but let you use the that class in another file.

What you need to do is `@NgModule.imports` the whatever module the components is in, into the other module of the component in which you are trying to use the other component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'other'
})
class OtherComponent {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ OtherComponent ],
  exports: [ OtherComponent ]
})
class OtherModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'consumer',
  template: '<other></other>'
})
class ConsumerComponent {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ OtherModule ],
  declarations: [ CosumerComponent ],
  exports: [ ConsumerComponent ]
})
class ConsumerModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work.  It's strange because I have imported my Nav component into another component without a module and it works great, rather than resorting to using modules.

Comment: If the components are declared in the same module, then it works. This is just how it is. If a component is declared in a different module, then that module needs to be imported into the module that the target component is in.